# Glue within a beamer block / beamercolorbox

Tags: beamer, spacing

How can one achieve that glue within a beamer `block` or a `beamercolorbox` reacts to spacing needs outside of it? In the following overfull slide one would expect that the glue shrinks to 0, but it does not.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Glue in box}
\begin{block}{Theorem}
Some text
\vskip30pt minus 30pt
More text
\end{block}
\lipsum[1]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]